# Mercurial - active changeset after a pull

Tags: mercurial

When you do an hg pull which results in multiple heads, which of the heads is 'active' on your file system?

Ie: Given a local repostory with changesets:

```
A1 - A2 - A3
```

And then doing an hg pull which results in multiple heads:

```
A1 - A2 - A3
        \
          B3
```

Prior to doing an hg merge, which changeset will be active on the file system?  Will it be A3 or B3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "active on the filesystem", but after doing `hg pull` the working directory is not changed. You need to do `hg update` to update the working folder to one of the pulled commits.

When doing `hg update` you can specify the changeset you need. If you don't, the working directory is updated to the tip of the current named branch.

Comment: Thanks.  What command can you use to see the changeset in the active directory?  When I use hg heads or hg parents I see both changesets.

Comment: @Marcus `hg parents` should be it. If it shows two changesets... maybe you did a `merge` and didn't commit it?

Comment: Hmm..  maybe I started my merge but didn't commit it.  That was probably the case.